# TSQL count uppcase and lowercase letters

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi I am writing some TSQL code practices, trying to count the vowels, lowercase and uppercase letter in a string, my code worked for vowels, but somehow it counts all letters as lowercase letters, Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(200) ='Abc Efg Hij'
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @numVowels int = 0
DECLARE @numLower int = 0
DECLARE @numUpper int = 0

WHILE @i <= LEN(@name)
    BEGIN
        IF PATINDEX('%' + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@name, @i, 1)) + '%', 'aeiou') > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @numVowels += 1
            END
        IF SUBSTRING(@name, @i, 1) BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z'
            BEGIN 
                SET @numLower += 1
            END
        ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@name, @i, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
            BEGIN
                SET @numUpper += 1
            END
        PRINT SUBSTRING(@name, @i, 1) 

        SET @i +=1
    END


PRINT 'There are ' + CAST((@numVowels) AS VARCHAR(200)) + ' vowels'
PRINT 'There are ' + CAST((@numLower) AS VARCHAR(200)) + ' lower-case letters'
PRINT 'There are ' + CAST((@numUpper) AS VARCHAR(200)) + ' upper-case letters'
```

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related to collation, but a few tests raised more questions in my mind than it solved. First, to have your code work, you just have to replace both occurrences of:

```
IF SUBSTRING(@name, @i, 1) BETWEEN ...
```

with

```
IF SUBSTRING(@name, @i, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN BETWEEN ...
```

Forcing a binary collation will prevent SQL Server from considering that `'a'` and `'A'` are equal.

Now the questions raised in my mind are:

- Why doesn't it work with a case sensitive collation like `Latin1_General_CS_AS` (9 lower-case, 0 upper-case) ? This was my first try as I was expecting your problem to be caused by a case insensitive collation, I expected it to be solved with a case-sensitive one
- Why does it partially work with `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` (8 lower-case, 1 upper-case) ? Only the first `'A'` is not considered as a lower-case character and I don't know why.

That's all I can get from the top my .NET developer's head. If you are looking for more information, maybe someone else here or at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ can provide more information.

Comment: thank you very much  @ybo  ! I am happy as long as `Latin1_General_BIN` works.

Comment: If you consider this a valid answer, please mark it as such, thanks!